# C# Object oriented return type "this" on child call

Tags: c#, oop, parent-child

I have 2 classes, each returns itself in all of the function:

```
public class Parent{
   public Parent SetId(string id){
      ...
      return this
   }
}

public class Child : Parent{
   public Child SetName(string id){
      ...
      return this
   }
}
```

I want to enable this kind of API:

```
new Child().SetId("id").SetName("name");
```

`SetName` cannot be accessed since `SetId` returns `Parent` and `SetName` is on the `Child`.

How?

Comment: @L.B - Parent can have many chids...

Comment: @L.B this is wrong because you do not know how many child classes you will have when your write Parent class and you cannot assume anything about Child existing inside Parent!

Comment: if you do not have a reference to Child class your (Child)this will not compile. if Child is not present at compile time...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you really want this fluent behavior, and the `Parent` class can be made abstract, then you could realize it like this:

```
public abstract class Parent<T> where T : Parent<T>
{
    public T SetId(string id) {
        return (T)this;
    }
}

public class Child : Parent<Child>
{
    public Child SetName(string id) {
        return this;
    }
}
```

It is now possible to write:

```
new Child().SetId("id").SetName("name");
```

Comment: +1 Better than my idea :) I knew there would be a way to use generics for that, but it didn't crossed my mind.

Comment: eh eh, faster and smarted than me as you got the solution. As it was done in java here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4031857/way-to-make-java-parent-class-method-return-object-of-child-class/4032924#4032924 +1 from me ;-)

Comment: @Davide Piras: Eric Lippert wrote an interesting article about these kind generic constructions: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/02/03/curiouser-and-curiouser.aspx

Answer (score 3):

I might be missing the point here, but it looks like your really just trying to set properties.  If you expose them as properties you can use an [object initializer call](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062.aspx).

```
var child = new Child()
{
    Id = value1;
    Name = value2;
}
```

You can also call a method instead of setting a value inside the intializer.

Answer (score 1):

I find it odd that you want to return a reference to the current instance of a class from within the current instance. Would you not already have such a reference, in order to access the properties and methods of the object? Might you be thinking about CLONING?

Unless I am missing something about your model, it seems that a propely set up initialization scheme, some boring Property definitions, and perhaps a factory class might be more like what you are looking for. It also seems like you MIGHT consider setting up your Parent with ID as an immutable property, although your requirements might create a bona-fide reason for doing so.

Here are some potentially useful class def's. It is early here in St. Louis, and I am not properly caffienated yet, so I might be missing something . . . ;-)

The Parent:

```
public class Parent
{

    protected string _id;

    // Protected default constructor so tht this class can be inherited:
    protected Parent() { }

    // REquired to set ID at initialization; 
    public Parent(String ID)
    {
        _id = ID;
    }

    // Read-only:
    public String ID
    {
        get { return _id; }
    }


    // This seems a little dodgy. Why would you want to return a reference
    // to the current instance as a result of resetting the ID?
    public Parent SetID(String ID)
    {
        _id = ID;
        return this;
    }
}
```

A Parent Factory:

```
public class ParentFactory
{
    public static Parent NewParent(String ID)
    {
        Parent newParent = new Parent(ID);
        return newParent;
    }
}
```

The Child:

```
public class Child : Parent
{

    private string _name;

    // Protected default constructor so tht this class can be inherited:
    protected Child() { }

    // Initialize a new Child with the ID property required for the parent:
    public Child(String ID)
    {
        base.SetID(ID);
    }


    // Initialize a new child with both properties set:
    public Child(String ID, String Name) : this(ID)
    {
        _name = Name;
    }

    // This could be read-only as well:
    public String Name
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set { _name = value; }
    }


    // Again, seems kinda dodgy: 
    public Child SetName(String name)
    {
        return this;
    }
}
```

A Child Factory:

```
public class ChildFactory
{
    public static Child  NewChild(String ID)
    {
        Child newChild = new Child(ID);
        return newChild;
    }


    public static Child  NewChild(String ID, String Name)
    {
        Child newChild = new Child(ID, Name);
        return newChild;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Davide Piras is right, a way to do it is to use a virtual method, or better an interface.

See this code

```
public interface INode
{
    INode SetName(string aName);
    INode SetId(string aId);
}

public class Parent : INode
{
    public virtual INode SetId(string id)
    {
        ...
        return this
    }

    public virtual INode SetName(string aId)
    {
        return this;
    }
}

public class Child : Parent
{
   public override INode SetName(string id)
   {
      ...
      return this;
   }
}
```

Comment: So I need to insert an interface that will have All of the Child's methods? (i mean methods that return this), but the problem is that ill expose one Chid methods to other Child, meybe they are not relevant.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to create a [fluent interface](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/FluentInterface.html). Are you sure that this is going to be the easiest way for developers to use these classes?

How about going with simple old properties for 'Name' and 'Id'? This is nice and easy to use, especially when using [Collection Initialiser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062.aspx) syntax.

Answer (score 0):

I found a similar question but for java language here: [Way to make Java parent class method return object of child class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4031857/way-to-make-java-parent-class-method-return-object-of-child-class/4032924#4032924)

tried to compile it but does not work, see my snipped and see my comment, basically looks like in Java we can cast this to T but in C# now. interesting...

(this is not the solution to your question I'm just reporting what I tried to do and how far I was able to get, if anybody knows some magic to get this working keeping such design... welcome :) )

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var obj = new Child().SetId("id").SetName("aaa");
    }
}

public class Parent<T>
{
    public virtual T SetId(string id)
    {
        // this does not work
        return (T)this;

        // this compiles but is NOT what we want :(
        //return default(T);
    }
}

public class Child : Parent<Child>
{
    public Child SetName(string name)
    {
        return this;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong with this:
        ((Child)(new Child().SetId("id")).SetName("name");

The explanation here is that although the runtime type of the object is Child, the static type inference C# uses when it compiles the expression you wanted to support is concluding that the static type of SetId("id") is Parent.  And it is, since SetId is defined in the Parent class.

In fact your object is of type Child, and has a SetName method.  Thus, SetName is available to you, but only if you tell C# to treat the object as a Child.  In your expression you don't, and but since Parent doesn't have a SetName method, your code won't typecheck, so it won't compile.

If you do the coersion C# will check the type just in case, but then it will do the invocation you had in mind.