# Inherited method returned reference type

Tags: java, generics, inheritance

I'm facing the problem described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4031857/way-to-make-java-parent-class-method-return-object-of-child-class) but would like to find a solution (if possible) without all the casts and @SuppressWarning annotations.

A better solution would be one that builds upon the referenced one by:

- removing @SuppressWarning
- removing casts

Solutions presented here will be graded with 2 points based on the criteria. Bounty goes to solution with most points or the "most elegant" one if there is more than one with 2 points.

Comment: Will add bounty in 2 days due to the SO mechanism for offering bounties. Feel free to post your answer now, though.

Comment: related: [Is there a way to refer to the current type with a type variable?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7354740/is-there-a-way-to-refer-to-the-current-type-with-a-type-variable)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No cast, no @SuppressWarning, few lines only:

```java
public abstract class SuperClass<T extends SuperClass<T>> {
    protected T that;
    public T chain() {
        return that;
    }
}

public class SubClass1 extends SuperClass<SubClass1> {
    public SubClass1() {
        that = this;
    }
}

public class SubClass2 extends SuperClass<SubClass2> {
    public SubClass2() {
        that = this;
    }
}
```

Comment: This was chosen as a best answer because it avoids casts entirely, has no @SuppresWarnings and is, according to me, the most elegant as it also avoids method overriding (the reference which you have to "override" looks cleaner and requires less code; it's also hidden from the user that you override anything at all). Will award bounty in 23hrs.

Comment: @pnt This is basically the same solution as the accepted answer in your referenced question. Why didn't you like it there and accept it here?

Comment: @FrancoisBourgeois Actually, this isn't the same solution. In the other solution, with `return (T) this;` in the abstract class, the complier can't know at compile time if the cast is safe (even if it can be, only the developer knows), thus the need of the @SuppressWarning annotation. In my solution, no need to cast since `that` is set directly within the subclass. And this *no-cast solution* is precisly what was asked here.

Comment: @pnt Why do you think this answer is better than the one below from Rohit? The person who would like to use this abstract class needs to know that he must assign `that = this` in the constructor. However, if he doesn't do it, then you don't get any warning, but your code will fail in runtime. With Rohit's answer below, you're required to override the method and return the correct instance, which is much better and less error-prone.

Answer (score 5):

One approach is to define an abstract method `getThis()` in `Parent` class, and make all the `Child` classes override it, returning the `this` reference. This is a way to recover the type of `this` object in a class hierarchy.

The code would look like this:

```
abstract class Parent<T extends Parent<T>> {

    protected abstract T getThis();

    public T example() {
        System.out.println(this.getClass().getCanonicalName());
        return getThis();          
    }
}

class ChildA extends Parent<ChildA> {

    @Override
    protected ChildA getThis() {
        return this;
    }

    public ChildA childAMethod() {
        System.out.println(this.getClass().getCanonicalName());
        return this;
    }
}

class ChildB extends Parent<ChildB> {

    @Override
    protected ChildB getThis() {
        return this;
    }

    public ChildB childBMethod() {
        return this;
    }
}


public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws NoSuchMethodException {
        ChildA childA = new ChildA();
        ChildB childB = new ChildB();

        childA.example().childAMethod().example();
        childB.example().childBMethod().example();
    }
}
```

As per requirement, there is no *Casting* and no *@SuppressWarnings*. I learnt this trick few days back from [Angelika Langer - Java Generics FAQs](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/JavaGenericsFAQ.html).

**Reference:**

- [How do I recover the actual type of the this object in a class hierarchy?](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/ProgrammingIdioms.html#How%20do%20I%20recover%20the%20actual%20type%20of%20the%20this%20object%20in%20a%20class%20hierarchy?)

Comment: You might want to make the declaration `Parent<T extends Parent<T>>`. Otherwise you could do `extends Parent<String>` and the method chaining would end at `String getThis()`.

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to override the method in the child class and change the return type to a more specific one, ie. the child type. This requires casting. Instead of using the typical `(Child)` cast, use the [`Class#cast(Object)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#cast%28java.lang.Object%29) method

```
public class Parent {
    public Parent example() {
        System.out.println(this.getClass().getCanonicalName());
        return this;
    }
}

public class Child extends Parent {
    public Child example() {
        return Child.class.cast(super.example());
    }

    public Child method() {
        return this;
    }
}
```

The cast is hidden within the standard method. From the source of `Class`.

```
public T cast(Object obj) {
    if (obj != null && !isInstance(obj))
        throw new ClassCastException(cannotCastMsg(obj));
    return (T) obj;
}
```

Comment: Not really a solution because it doesn't remove the casts (just wraps and hides them) and doesn't solve the original problem in the referenced question. Yes, of course you could override the method to return a more specific type but the whole point is to re-use it and not have to override it in each child.

Comment: @pnt The problem stated was _I want to implement this without using additional interfaces and extra methods, and to use this without class casts, auxiliary arguments and so on._ The thing is you can't. The solutions proposed all have either extra methods and/or extra arguments. Either you override the method in question or you introduce another method in the parent and override that. In the Generics solution, you also need to introduce a type parameter.