# Fluent API with inheritance for validators - input validator instance seems identified as parent class

Tags: java, fluent-interface

I'm writing a fluent API to validate `key:value` pair in a Map. I have a hierarchy of validator types. I referred to one answer from [Fluent API with inheritance and generics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23731270/fluent-api-with-inheritance-and-generics).

```
public interface IValidator {
    IValidator assertValue(String key, String expectedValue) throws Exception;

    abstract class Abstract implements IValidator {

        protected final Map<String, String> resultMap = new HashMap<>();

        @Override
        public <T extends IValidator> T assertValue(String key, String expectedValue) throws Exception {
            ...
            return (T) this;
    }
}
```

The 2nd level abstract subclasses redefine the parent type as follows.

```
public abstract class AbstractValidator
extends IValidator.Abstract {
    // other logic not related to assertion
}
```

The concrete subclasses redefine the parent type similarly.

```
public class ExampleValidator
extends AbstractValidator
{
    public ExampleValidator assertPromptId(String expectedValue) throws Exception{
        assertValue(PROMPT_ID, expectedValue);
        return  this;
    }

    public ExampleValidator assertNameSpace(String expectedValue ) throws Exception{
        assertValue(NAMESPACE, expectedValue);
        return this;
    }

    @Override
    public ExampleValidator assertValue(String key, String  expectedVlaue) throws Exception {
        super.assertValue(key, expectedVlaue);
        return this;
    }
```

Now, my test case is as follows. My issue is `.withValidator(Ivalidator validator)` was not able to find method of `assertPromptId()` and `assertNameSpace()` but only `assertValue()`. So how to fix it?

```
public class AssertionContext {
    public <T extends IValidator> T withValidator(IValidator validator) throws Exception {
        return (T) validator;
    }
} 

// test method in main
public void invocationTest() throws Throwable {
        AssertionContext verify = new AssertionContext();
        verify.withValidator(new ExampleValidator()).assertNameSpace("...");
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually I found the solution is very simple.

```
public <T extends IValidator> T withValidator(T t) throws Exception {
    ...
    return t;
}
```