# How do you make subclasses of a class return right type Java

Tags: java

I have a class with a method which returns a list of objects of that class:

```java
public class Parent {
    public static List<Parent> all_possible(int i) {
        //...
    }

    //other methods
}
```

I'm trying to make a Child class that also has this method, except it returns a list of the Child class.
With the code above, I have to rewrite it for the child class because the types are wrong:

```java
public class Child extends Parent {
    public static List<Child> all_possible(int i) {
        //same thing as above except different type
    }
    
    //child methods
}
```

Is it possible to write this in a way so all the children who inherit from this class use the right type?
Or is there a better way to do this?

Also, is it possible to have variables that change type similarly? For instance:

```java
public class Parent {
    public static List<Parent> objects;
}
//...
public class Child extends Parent {
    public static List<Child> objects;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Edit:
[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4031857/way-to-make-java-parent-class-method-return-object-of-child-class) stackoverflow post explains how to do it with instance methods, but it doesn't explain how to do it with static methods or static variables.

Apparently that is impossible, so what is the alternative I should use?

Comment: What do you mean by "the children who inherit from this class use the right type"?

Comment: static methods melong to the class, i.e. they are not inherited

Comment: Seems to be a duplicate of this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4031857/way-to-make-java-parent-class-method-return-object-of-child-class

Correct me if this does not answer the question.

Comment: I want the children who inherit from the class use themselves as the type.

Comment: @LayneBernardo That's exactly what I was looking for. The only question it doesn't answer is is this good practice?

Comment: Hahaha, that's always a question. I'm not a Java dev so I don't really know what is and isn't accepted as "good practice" but that answer looks similar to how I would do something like that in C++.

Comment: Also @fps static methods are inherited. You can easily test it yourself.

Comment: You _cannot_ make static methods behave like you want here, but the duplicate describes how to make it work with instance methods.  It is perfectly fine practice.

Comment: @Joshiepillow Granted, static methods *from classes* are inherited, but cannot be overriden

Comment: I guess this isn't a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4031857/way-to-make-java-parent-class-method-return-object-of-child-class then, because I am asking about static methods and variables. I edited the question to reflect that

Comment: There's only one practical alternative, which is to just...define those methods yourself for each class.  You can define helpers if you like, but you have to redeclare the method for each class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing some testing, I made a semi-solution.

I turned the static variable `objects` into a `HashMap<Type, ArrayList<Parent>>`

Then when I get a list of all the objects, I access the `objects` with the type of the Child.

Code:

```java
class Parent {
    private static Map<Type, List<Parent>> objects = new HashMap<>();
    public static List<Parent> all(Class c) {
        //...
        return objects.get(c);
    }
    public static List<Parent> all() {
        return all(Parent.class);
    }
    //...
}

class Child {
    public static List<Child> getAll() {
        return (List<Child>)(List<?>)getAll(Child.class);
    }
    //...
}
```

Not a perfect solution, as I still have to write a bit of code in every child class, but it's the best I could find.

Answer (score 0):

As described [before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10291949/are-static-methods-inherited-in-java), static methods *cannot be overridden*, but the subclass implementation hides the superclass implementation, that is, child's static method is called only when called from reference to `Child` class.

Example code:

```java
    static class Parent {
        static List<Parent> objects = new ArrayList<>();
        final String name; 

        public Parent(String name) {
            this.name = name;
            Parent.objects.add(this);
        }
        
        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return name;
        }
        
        static List<? extends Parent> all() {
            return new ArrayList<>(Parent.objects);
        }
        
        public List<? extends Parent> allPossible(int i) {
            return new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(new Parent("instance.parent.1"), new Parent("instance.parent.2")));
        }
    }
```

```java
    static class Child extends Parent {
        static List<Child> objects = new ArrayList<>();
        
        static List<Child> all() {
            return new ArrayList<>(Child.objects); 
        }
        
        public Child(String name) {
            super(name);
            Child.objects.add(this);
        }
        
        @Override
        public List<Child> allPossible(int i) {
            return new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(new Child("instance.child.1")));
        }
    }
```

Test:

```java
System.out.println("instance");
Parent p = new Parent("main.p");
Parent c = new Child("main.c");  // Child instance referenced by Parent variable

System.out.println(p.allPossible(2));
System.out.println(c.allPossible(2));
System.out.println("static");
System.out.println("p.all: " + p.all());
System.out.println("c.all: " + c.all());
System.out.println("Child.all: " + Child.all());
System.out.println("\nobjects");
System.out.println("p.objects: " + p.objects);
System.out.println("c.objects: " + c.objects);
System.out.println("Child.objects: " + Child.objects);
```

Output:

```
instance
[instance.parent.1, instance.parent.2]
[instance.child.1]
static
p.all: [main.p, main.c, instance.parent.1, instance.parent.2, instance.child.1]
c.all: [main.p, main.c, instance.parent.1, instance.parent.2, instance.child.1]
Child.all: [main.c, instance.child.1]

objects
p.objects: [main.p, main.c, instance.parent.1, instance.parent.2, instance.child.1]
c.objects: [main.p, main.c, instance.parent.1, instance.parent.2, instance.child.1]
Child.objects: [main.c, instance.child.1]
```